# .net Core select dropdown is very slow

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In my website, I have got 2 select dropdown list Client and Staff. 
I have got roughly 100 Clients and 350 Staffs.

Populating dropdown list is very slow. for example for the staff dropdown list takes around 40sec and little less for Client. basically it takes 1 minuted to load the page.

First I used ViewData

```
 ViewData["EmployeeList"] = new SelectList(employeeRepository.Employees.,"EmployeeID", "FullName");
```

cshtm

```
 <select asp-for="EmployeeID" class="form-control col-sm-12" asp-items="ViewBag.EmployeeList"></select>
```

Then I changed it to ViewModel

```
EmplSelectList = new SelectList(employeeRepository.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FullName")
```

cshtml

```
 <select asp-for="ClientID" class="form-control col-sm-12" asp-items="Model.ClientSelectList"></select>
```

This didn't improve much.

Does anyone know a better way to solve this issue? Please.
Thanks advance for help.

Comment: What is your code for `employeeRepository.Employees`? Knowing that might help us figure out what's going on. It's most likely to do with how you are querying the DB, not inserting the data into the `select` controls.

Comment: Hi, computercarguy. EmployeeRepository just gets list of the active employee from the DB. when I run the software with breakpoints. Retrieving employee from DB is very quick but passing this employee list to the cshtml and populating the website takes quite long time.

Comment: You could be falling victim to Lazy Loading, which makes a DB query seem fast and delays the read until you actually use the data, making other things seem slow. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_lazy_loading.htm  This is why we need to see more code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example