# Cascade Dropdown not trigger

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core. I have the following controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, string nomor)
    {
        if (id == null || nomor == null || _context.Mfbnkcoms == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        //var model = await _context.Mfbnkcoms.FindAsync(id);
        var model = await _context.Mfbnkcoms.Where(x => x.MfbnkcomBankId == id && x.MfbnkcomNoRekening == nomor).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        if (model == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var glaccountselect =
          _context.Mfcoas
            .Select(s => new
            {
                AccId = s.MfcoaAccount,
                AccDescription = $"{s.MfcoaAccount} -- £{s.MfcoaDes}"
            })
            .ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

public IActionResult GetSubAccount(string sid)
    {
        //var SubAccountList = _context.Mfsoas.Where(s => s.MfsoaAcc == sid).Select(c => new { Id = c.MfsoaAccount, Name = c.MfsoaAccount }).ToList();
        var SubAccountList = _context.Mfsoas.Where(s => s.MfsoaAcc == sid).Select(c => new { Id = c.MfsoaAccount, Name = string.Format("{0}-- £{1}", c.MfsoaAccount, c.MfsoaDes) }).ToList();
        return Json(SubAccountList);
    }
```

On the View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="GLAccount" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">GL Account</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select asp-for="MfbnkcomAccount" asp-items="ViewBag.Glaccount" class="form-control select2" name="GLAccount" id="GLAccount" data-live-search="true" data-size="11">
        <option value="">-- Select Account --</option>
    </select>
</div>

<label for="SubAccount" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Sub Account</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select asp-for="MfbnkcomSubAcc" class="form-control select2" name="SubAccount" id="SubAccount" data-live-search="true" data-size="11">
        <option value="">-- Select SubAccount --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.10/select2-bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-CbQfNVBSMAYmnzP3IC+mZZmYMP2HUnVkV4+PwuhpiMUmITtSpS7Prr3fNncV1RBOnWxzz4pYQ5EAGG4ck46Oig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.select2').select2({
        theme: "bootstrap"
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("select#GLAccount").change(function () {
            var sid = $(this).val();

            $("select#SubAccount").empty();

            $.getJSON(`/BankCompanies/GetSubAccount?sid=${sid}`, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("select#SubAccount").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

I have an `Index` page which is the list of the data. When I click `Edit` button on the table. It will redirect to `Edit` page. The edit page will show with the detail of the selected data.

All data appears, only data on `SubAccount` select is not shown. How this is happen? 
Advice please.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: Seem likes you're not assigning anything for the `SubAccount` property in your edit action so the ddl will alway be empty

Comment: @Izzy, If I debug on this line `var model = await _context.Mfbnkcoms.Where(x => x.MfbnkcomBankId == id && x.MfbnkcomNoRekening == nomor).SingleOrDefaultAsync();`... It has a data on `model` variable. Why?

Comment: @QingGuo, no error message. the data just not appear on the dropdown. should be appear and the item on the `subaccount` dropdown is the list after filtered by `Glaccount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code and set breakpoint at `GetSubAccount` ,but it won't excute the `GetSubAccount` method. Try to change your code :

```
$(function () {
        $("select#GLAccount").change(function () {
            var sid = $(this).val();

            $("select#SubAccount").empty();

            $.getJSON(`/BankCompanies/GetSubAccount?sid=${sid}`, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("select#SubAccount").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
                });
            });
        })
    });
```

into( remove `$(function () {`):

```
$("select#GLAccount").on("change", function () { 
   // or 
   //$("select#GLAccount").change(function () {
                var sid = $(this).val();

                $("select#SubAccount").empty();

                $.getJSON(`/BankCompanies/GetSubAccount?sid=${sid}`, function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("select#SubAccount").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
                    });
                });
            });
```

result:
[image]

**Update**

Add below in your edit action:

```
 ViewBag.SubAccountList = _context.Mfsoas
.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text =  $"{s.MfcoaAccount} -- £{s.MfcoaDes}", Value = s.MfcoaAccount.ToString()  })
.ToList();
```

And add `asp-items="ViewBag.SubAccountList"`  :

```
<label for="SubAccount" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Sub Account</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select asp-for="MfbnkcomSubAcc" asp-items="ViewBag.SubAccountList" class="form-control select2" name="SubAccount" id="SubAccount" data-live-search="true" data-size="11">
        <option value="">-- Select SubAccount --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the different?

Comment: @Haminteu , what do you mean ? Is this way not work ?

Comment: Yes, still.. not working. Also, I am using bootstrap select. Do you think this is the cause?

Comment: @Haminteu I mean remove `$(function () {`  . You can use `$("select#GLAccount").change(function () {` or  `$("select#GLAccount").on("change", function () {`

Comment: Yes, I did. But still not working.

Comment: @Haminteu  Do you set breakpoint at `GetSubAccount method(string sid)` what  `sid` can you see ?

Comment: when I click edit from Index page. the `GetSubAccount` is not triggered. But when I change the value of Glaccount, its triggered.

Comment: @Haminteu Yeah, you trigger the GetSubAccount by change the value of Glaccount, that's why click edit from Index page, the GetSubAccount is not triggered. So what do you want ? I am confused.

Comment: It should be retrieve and loaded from database when I clicked edit from the index page.

Comment: @Haminteu If you want to it be retrieve and loaded from database , you need to get data then use  ViewBag to pass SubAccount,  like: `asp-items="ViewBag.Glaccount"`  .

Comment: Could you please put it as an answer please. So I can tick it as an answer.

Comment: @Haminteu  , Ok ,  have a look at my update.

Comment: great, that is work. Thank you so much. but it seems that there's a delay to load the data on `subaccount` select.

Comment: @Haminteu  You are welcome:) .Glad it can work. "but it seems that there's a delay to load the data on subaccount select." You can read  [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527001/net-core-select-dropdown-is-very-slow)  and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391409/entity-framework-core-6-lazy-loading-takes-loading-data-when-needed-too-litera) to know more.